# Export then import products with images to different server

Tags: magento-2.1, import, export

I only have admin panel access to magento 2 site.  I need to export all products to a new site on different hosting where I have full access.

I ran a product export but the image URLs are local paths so the import doesn't include the images.  I have read documentation and can't see anyway to make it use external links for the images.

How do I export with the external image URL?

Comment: https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/how-to-import-product-images-into-magento-2.html

Answer (score 0):

When you export the csv, the exported csv contains path of image from your local server, for example if your image name is test.jpg, the path of your image is pub/media/import/t/e/test.jpg. In csv, you get only /t/e/test.jpg and pub/media/import is default path. Also, the path  /t/e/test.jpg is formed with first two letters of your corresponding name of your image.

So, while importing it in new site , you have to replace it with url https://yourdomain.com/pub/media/import/t/e/test.jpg